# Neovim: How to copy a visual block (each line might have different length) and paste the content without adding any extra spaces?

Tags: copy-paste, neovim

I am used to copying a block/column, and each row might have a different length, and when I paste in between (let's say quotes) "", there is no space added.  Many editors do this without any padding in the result.

| Source block |
| --- |
| House |
| Car |
| Garage |
| Buses |

| Target |
| --- |
| The " " is big |
| One " " per house |
| The " " is for the car |
| The " " is late |

| I expect this Result |
| --- |
| The "House" is big |
| One "Car" per house |
| The "Garage" is for the car |
| The "Buses" is late |

I am used in vscode to have that result using cursors. In nvim is different.  This is the sequence.

```
I move to the source first row.
Ctrl-v to select the first position for all the source
Press $ to select the end of each row.
type y to yank the rows
Move to the target after the first quote (")
Ctrl-v and select one character only for all the rows in the target.
Press p
```

The result is different from vscode

| Nvim Result (spaces added at the end) |
| --- |
| The "House " is big |
| One "Car " per house |
| The "Garage" is for the car |
| The "Buses " is late |

I reported it as a bug in nvim, but they told me that it is supposed to work like that based on the documentation.
Do you know how to do this? or maybe a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$`by `$h`which moves to *before* the end of the line.

I still need to redo many of my yanks because I forget the `h` which is quite confusing.

Maybe there is a better way to configure that behavior, would be great to learn about it, but at least this should do the trick.

Comment: Not quite there yet.  The issue is neovim tries to have a block with rows the same size.  It adds spaces to the smallest words to accomplish that.  Let's say I have a row with a word of  3 characters and one or more of 10 characters.  It adds 7 spaces to the smallest one.  So, I have to remove those extra spaces manually.

Comment: oh I see I tested badly, sorry